# What the best way to check if path exists in array?

Tags: typescript

If I had simple and unchangeable path like `exampleObject['first']['second']`, it would so easy to check it. But I have a path which is dynamic. Therefore I put the keys to an array `['first', 'second']` and then want to check, if array with that route exists.

Do you know a method which will help me?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and its [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) function (`npm i lodash && npm i --save-dev @types/lodash`):

```
Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
import * as _ from "lodash"; // or import { get } from "lodash"

// Get by path without default value
if (!_.isUndefined(_.get(exampleObject, 'first.second')) {
  // Not undefined
  // ...
}
```

**Edit:** I have read your question again and I am not so sure anymore, that my answer might help you. Maybe you can clarify your question a bit, so that I can improve my answer.